# static const double/float in a class ,ok or not ok, please give me a current answer

Tags: c++, c++11

Last time I am puzzled with the initialization of static const int ,const int and static int , then some kind men help me. But question comes again,

I try these int C_free 5.0

```
class Q{

   static const double qs = 10;//float is also ok

};
```

Then I try it in Qt creator 2.8.1 ,this can't pass .

So for understand this completely, Can anyone give me a whole explanation, under which situation which type is allowed ? not just int type. Thanks.

Forgive me , new C++ learner , not good English

Comment: The type has to be integral to initialize it in the class definition (for `const` static data members).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
using T = sometype;
class Q
{
    static const T qs = somevalue;
};
```

… `T` must be an integral type or an enumeration type:

C++11 §9.4.2/3

> **”**
>   If a non-volatile `const static` data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class
>   definition can specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in which every *initializer-clause* that is an *assignment-expression* is a constant expression.

The meaning of *constant expression* here is essentially that it can be evaluated at compile time; it is defined by C++11 §5.19/3.

---

C++11 `constexpr` allows a much wider ranger of types, if all relevant compilers support it.

---

A simple alternative is to do this:

```
class Q
{
    static
    auto qs() -> double { return somevalue; }
};
```

And a more elaborate alternative, the templated const trick:

```
template< class Dummy_ >
struct Q_constants_
{
    static double const qs;
};

template< class Dummy_ >
double Q_constants<Dummy_>::qs = somevalue;

class Q
    : public Q_constants_<void>
{};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the draft standard has to say about initialization of `const static` member data:

> 9.4.2/3 If a non-volatile `const static` data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in which every *initializer-clause* that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression (5.19). A `static` data member of literal type can be declared in the class definition with the `constexpr` specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in which every *initializer-clause* that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression.

You have the choice of changing the type of `qs` to an integral type or change it to a `constexpr` instead of `const`.

Use:

```
class Q
{
   static const int qs = 10;
};
```

or

```
class Q 
{
   static constexpr double qs = 10;
};
```